# wtsapi32.dll : WTSEnumerateSessions API sets 'pCount' to 0 intermittently

Tags: c#, winapi

I am using `WTSEnumerateSessions` API to get User sessions on RDP.

I am taking reference of [this](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wtsapi32.wtsenumeratesessions) and code looks like below,

```
    IntPtr ppSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

    Int32 pCount = 0;
    Int32 retval = WTSEnumerateSessions(server, 0, 1, ref ppSessionInfo, ref pCount);
    Log.Write(pCount.ToString());
    Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));

    Int64 current = (int)ppSessionInfo;

    if (retval != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pCount; i++)
        {
           WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)current, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
           current += dataSize;

           ret.Add(si.SessionID + " " + si.State + " " + si.pWinStationName);
        }

        WTSFreeMemory(ppSessionInfo);
    }
```

It works fine in most of the case, but on specific machine, logic fails because it gets `pCount` 0. Here my question is, In which scenarios `WTSEnumerateSessions` sets `pCount` to 0?

Note: this code runs into System user and while running machine can be locked or disconnected or logged off.

I have explicitly added logs to get the value of count, and it was 0.

Comment: This code does not yell nearly loud enough when the function fails.  It just silently does nothing and makes it look like pCount = 0.  You must `throw new Win32Exception()` instead.

Comment: @HansPassant I have explicitly added logs to get the value of count, and it was 0.

Comment: We can't tell if your logging code is correct.  Always post the real code you are having a problem with.  And always write correct code where you can, this is not so must be changed.

Comment: May not relate at all to your current problem but I'm deeply suspicious of code that includes `Int64 current = (int)ppSessionInfo` before actually using `IntPtr` type. If `ppSessionInfo` doesn't fit in 32 bits and you're in an unchecked context, that's going to send you off into the weeds.

Comment: Yup, your Log.Write() statement can't tell you either that the function failed.  You *must* know what the failure looks like to diagnose the mishap.  Throw that exception.

Comment: @HansPassant I Understand you point. However in Log.Write() method, we are simply writing the value as it is in log file. And in that log file, I can see an entry of '0' , there is no exception in this method and I am getting 0 as pCount. (Yes in such case I should throw an exception to the caller). But what can be possible reason behind pCount being 0.

Comment: You still don't get it.  When the function fails there will **not** be an exception, failure is indicated by its return value.  This is normal for C functions.  It will not modify the pCount variable when it fails, so it is still 0.  A defensive way to write this code is to initialize it to -1, now your log can actually indicate failure.  But that still doesn't tell you *why* it failed, what you need to know to actually do something about it.  Throw the exception.

Comment: @Amit what is the value of `retval` when `pCount` is 0? Your logging does not say. If `WTSEnumerateSessions()` fails, `retval` will be set to 0, which you don't check. To then find out WHY `WTSEnumerateSessions()` failed, you need to call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` or throw a `Win32Exception` (either way, make sure your declaration of `WTSEnumerateSessions()` has `SetLastError=true` in its `DllImport` attributes).

Comment: @RemyLebeau `retVal` is also 0. We have confirmed that. And yes 'SetLastError' is set to true. That's good idea (and also suggested by Hans) I should check for the Last Error or Throw `Win32Exception` .   Thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, Now I got that. thanks.

Comment: @Amit if `retVal` is 0, the value of `pCount` is meaningless. Handle the error and move on.